# I accidentally deleted the contents of .gnome2 folder in ubuntu 12.04, can I recover?

Tags: 12.04

The following were deleted... how worried should I be?

accels/nautilus, Directory:accels, keyrings/user.keystore, keyrings/user.keystore.46SN8V, keyrings/login.keyring, Directory:keyrings, Directory:nautilus-scripts

Answer (score 0):

You can log in as another user (or the Guest Session) and copy the .gnome2 folder into your actual Home Folder (located at /Home/Your_User), although, many program settings or configurations will be reseted until you change them again.

Good Luck!